# preg match all get group multiple times

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get a regular expression to get a subgroup everytime it is found.  This is my code:

```
$string2 = 'cabbba';
preg_match_all('#c(a(b)*a)#',$string2,$result3,PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($result3);
```

My goal is to get 'b' as a captured group each time (so 3 times). This codes outputs the following:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'cabbba' (length=6)
      1 => string 'abbba' (length=5)
      2 => string 'b' (length=1)
```

I want it to show 'b' each times it appears, so something like this

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'cabbba' (length=6)
      1 => string 'abbba' (length=5)
      2 => array (size=3)
         0 => string 'b' (length 1)
         1 => string 'b' (length 1)
         2 => string 'b' (length 1)
```

This is a simplified example, in the real code the subpattern 'b' will be different each time, but it follows the same pattern.

Comment: `(b)*` captures only the last `b` in more b's..

Comment: Yes, and my question is how to fetch all (in different groups, so not (b*))

Comment: This is impossible using regexps since they are state machines.

Comment: you could do like this https://regex101.com/r/cX2oW4/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be possible only through `\G` anchor.

```
(?:ca|\G)(b)(?=b|(a))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cX2oW4/2)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a *non-greedy* modifier for your `b*`?

```
$string2 = 'cabbba';
preg_match_all('#c(a(b)*?a)#', $string2, $result3, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($result3);
```

*Excuse me if it's not what you asked, I'm not sure I really understood your needs...*

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, previous answer is wrong, please ignore it...
I'm trying to elaborate a right one...
Just trying something like

```
preg_match_all('#c(a(?:(b{1}))*a)#', $string2, $result3, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

but it doesn't work, either... :-(

**UPDATE 2:**
See `Avinash Raj` answer, I think it's quite good...

Comment: To clarify more, b* gets all three b's. I want this to create 3 captured groups, but (b)* only returns one captured group.